# How do i get a randomly selected string name and still select an existing substring without the code coming out as text

Tags: string, object, random, discord.js

I'm currently trying to get info off of an object but that's randomly selected. I believe that the true problem is that what I wrote is not being taken as a variable for selecting an existing object if not as the variable for the object, I don't know if this is a clear message or not.

Example of what I have tried:

```
let PK = ["Random1", "Random2", "Random3"]
let PKS = Math.floor(Math.random() * PK.length)

let Random1 = {
    name: "Random1",
    number: "010"
  }

let Random2 = {
        name: "Random2",
        number: "011"
      }

if(message.content.toLowerCase() == "random"){
message.channel.send(PK[PKS].number)
}
```

There is another thing I have tried which is by using `${}`. These are the results:
"Random1.number" or "Random2.number" when what I was looking for is actually "010" or "011".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap your objects inside some collection such as an Array and then you just compare the value from your random selection to the value find in the collection (if any (randoms)):

```js
let PK = ["Random1", "Random2", "Random3"];
let PKS = Math.floor(Math.random() * PK.length);

const randoms = [
    {
        name: "Random1",
        number: "010",
    },
    {
        name: "Random2",
        number: "011",
    },
];

if (message.content.toLowerCase() == "random") {
    const findRandom = randoms.find((v) => v.name === PK[PKS]);
    if (findRandom) {
        message.channel.send(findRandom.number);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to say.

Comment: You should provide additional information about the code you provided. For example, why does this code answers the question and how?

Comment: There is an error saying "randoms.find is not a function"